# T-student with when two samples have 0 variance

Tags: statistics, average, mean

Hello I'm trying to have a better understanding on the t-student method.

I have two distincts groups that gave me answers to 10 questions as such :

> On a scale from 1 to 5, how much do you ...

1. Group 1 answered 1 for every questions.
2. Group 2 answered 5 for every questions.

I would like to say that there is a significant difference in group answers, and chose to use a t-student. Here is what I've done so far :

```
Sum of group 1 answers : 10
Sum of group 2 answers : 50
Avg1 : Average score group 1 = 1
Avg2 : Average score group 2 = 5

SS1 : Sum square of answers from group 1 = 10
SS2 : Sum square of answers from group 2 = 250
SD1 : Sum Square of deviation of group 1. (SS1 - Sum of group 1 answers² / 10 = 0.
SD2 : Sum Square of deviation of group 2, (SS2 - Sum of group 2 answers² / 10 = 0.
```

Questions from group 1 and group 2 are independant.

I then struggle to calculate t because the formula I'm using is as follows :

```
t = (Avg1 - Avg2) / Root( (SD1+SD2) / (10+10-2) * (1/10 + 1/10) )
```

And I have a null denominator value.

May someone help me understand my mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Student's t-test compares the averages of the two groups, in terms of the standard error(s).  In simple terms, a t-test asks "how many standard errors are they apart?"

The problem is that your groups have standard deviation = 0, which means your standard errors = 0.  Student's t-test makes a number of mathematical assumptions, one of which is that there's at least *some* spread in your data (otherwise, you probably wouldn't be doing a test!)

So no, this isn't a result of anything wrong in your t-test calculation, it's just your data.

Maybe an alternative could be a chi-squared test, and simplify your data to categorical.  Here's what it would look like in R:

```
data <- matrix(c(10,0,0,10), nrow=2, ncol=2)
rownames(data) <- c("group 1","group 2")
colnames(data) <- c("low","high")

data
##         low high
## group 1  10    0
## group 2   0   10

chisq.test(data)
## 
##  Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
## 
## data:  data
## X-squared = 16.2, df = 1, p-value = 5.699e-05
```

The tiny p-value (0.000057) tells you what you already know - there's a big difference in survey response proportions between groups.

Comment: Thanks alot for the explanation !